# Calculate Sum with Fixted Time Interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like mentioned below:

```
Time         Price
09:15:18     27,725 
09:15:49     27,721 
09:16:19     27,696 
09:16:32     27,699 
09:17:49     27,728 
09:18:19     27,742 
09:19:19     27,834 
09:20:19     27,890 
09:20:49     27,890 
09:21:49     27,936 
09:22:19     27,910 
09:23:19     27,921 
09:23:49     27,924 
09:24:19     27,927 
...
```

Say Start_Time = 09:15:00 (Fixed) & Sum_Interval = 10 Mins

I want to find sum of `Price` every 10 mins.

```
Row1 = Like Sum of Price from 9:15:00 to 9:24:59
Row1 = Like Sum of Price from 9:25:00 to 9:34:59
Row1 = Like Sum of Price from 9:35:00 to 9:44:59
...
```

Sample Result I want like mentioned below:

Result:

```
Time    Price
09:15   389453
09:25   418261
09:35   568241
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary, convert to numeric
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
#convert column to timedeltas
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))

Start_Time = '09:15:00'
Sum_Interval = '10Min'

#create timedelta range with maximum timedelta
r = pd.timedelta_range(pd.Timedelta(Start_Time), df['Time'].max(), freq=Sum_Interval)

#create bins by pd.cut, aggregate sum
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Time'], bins=r, labels=r[:-1]))['Price'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
      Time   Price
0 09:15:00  389543
```

If need `Time` values in strings in output:

```
r = pd.timedelta_range(pd.Timedelta(Start_Time), df['Time'].max(), freq=Sum_Interval)
lab = r[:-1].astype(str).str[:-3]

df = (df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Time'],bins=r,labels=lab))['Price']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='Price_Sum'))
print (df)
    Time  Price_Sum
0  09:15     389543
```

Comment: Sir, how to keep the sum value of price in different column say Price_Sum

Comment: Change last .reset_index()` to `.reset_index(name='Price_Sum')`

Comment: Sir, is it possibe to do with aggregate. Like find sum of the Price Column in **Price_Sum** and Count the number of rows in **Row_Count**

Comment: @RohitLambaK - yes, then use `.agg([(' Price_Sum','sum'), ('Row_Count','size')]).reset_index()` instead `.sum()
        .reset_index(name='Price_Sum')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use resample

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df['Price'] =  df['Price'].str.replace(',','').astype(int) 
df = df.set_index('Time')

df.resample('10Min').sum()
```

Comment: Unfortunately in your solution is not possible set `Start_Time`